# Create a nested file while redirecting output

Tags: linux, macos

In linux/OSx/etc, how can we redirect output to file inside a dir, where even dir needs to be created by this redirection.

basically, how to make sure that below command creates "dir1" and then sends output to "file1" inside "dir1"

```
echo "abc" > dir1/file1
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with one command, you have to use `mkdir`:

```
filename="dir1/file1"
mkdir -p "$(dirname "$filename")" && echo "abc" > "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can it with this one liner -

```
if [ ! -d "dir1" ]; then mkdir "dir1"; fi && echo "abc" > dir1/file1
```